# Angular 2: decimalPipe result -> convert back to number?

Tags: angular

number in `<input>` element formatted by `this.decimalPipe.transform(...)`
User changed value, then I need get this string value from input element and convert it back to number for further actions.
How to do reverse operation - convert string back from decimalPipe result to number?

Comment: inputFiled.Value may be '1,234.56' or '1.234,56' or something else - it depends on Angular LOCALE_ID. Please dont answers like parseFloat, Number() etc.

Comment: so I guess Angular dosn't have such feature...

Answer (score 1):

The best option for me is to use: [ng2-currency-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask) directive for clean coding.

```
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', precision: 2 }"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question.